# Is there any way in forge, to drop pins and draw boundaries in the pdf

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk, forge

i need to drop pins to a 2d drawing in the forge viewer and also divide 2d drawing in different zones/area. is it possible to do that with forge viewer?

Comment: There's an extension for basic 2D annotations in the viewer. See [Using Autodesk.Viewing.MarkupsCore extension](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/using-autodeskviewingmarkupscore-extension). Would that help?

Comment: have you had a chance to look at the markup extension, or at the other links suggested in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Petr's suggestion.  Take a look at this blog post, on how to add markup (so you can drop a pin).
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/viewing-large-ocrterrain-images-forge-viewer

To divide the 2d drawing into different zones, do you mean split screen ?  A bit like this split screen ... 
https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/compare-two-2d-documents-using-forge-viewer

If so, take a look at split viewer code here: https://github.com/wallabyway/2DCompare/blob/80564eea77dcc404a799d68a446cb918952ed8d4/docs/extensions/PixelCompare/PixelCompare.min.js#L235-L268